# $Re(f)=Re(g)$ implies $f(z)=g(z)+ic$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be analystic in a region $G$. If $\Re(f)=\Re(g)$ in $G$, then prove

$$f(z)=g(z)+ic \tag{for all $z \in G$}$$

where $c$ is a real constant.

By cauchy riemann we have

$$\int \frac{\partial}{\partial y}Re(g)=-\int\frac{\partial}{\partial x}Re(g)$$

Hence, $Im(f)$ must be some constant?

Comment: Did a few minor edits.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $f-g$ has values in $i\mathbb{R}$ and if $f-g$ is non-constant, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) its image must be open in $\mathbb{C}$, which is a contradiction. Whence the result.

Comment: what is the contradiction?

Comment: @R_Squared A non-constant holomorphic map has an open image : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis).

Answer (score 0):

I would use Cauchy-Riemann to do it like this:

Set

$h(z) = h_R(z) + ih_I(z) = f(z) - g(z); \tag 1$

then

$\Re(h) = h_R(z) = 0; \tag 2$

now by Cauchy-Riemann

$h_{I, x} = -h_{R,y} = 0 \tag 3$

and

$h_{I, y} = h_{R, x} = 0; \tag 4$

it follows that

$\nabla h_I = 0 \tag 5$

in $G$; thus,

$h_I = c \in \Bbb R, \tag 6$

where $c$ is constant.  So

$f(z) - g(z) = h(z) = h_R(z) + ih_I(z) = 0 + ic = ic, \tag 7$

whence

$f(z) = g(z) + ic. \tag 8$